# EventProcessorClient partition ownership management

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

How does partition lease ownership management works in EventProcessorClient? There is an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-processor-balance-partition-load#partition-ownership-tracking) with high level description but I am looking for more details, like lease management, timings, expiration etc.
Note: question is about EventProcessorClient, not EventProcessorHost.

Answer (score 1):

The `EventProcessorClient` uses a conservative approach to claiming partitions intended to allow processors to cycle up without having partitions "bounce" between them as they fight for ownership until things have stabilized.

The load balancing cycle ticks every 10 seconds, at which point the processor will determine whether or not to claim an additional partition.  Partition ownership uses a 30 second lease, which is used primarily to determine when a partition may have been orphaned; each cycle, the lease for claimed partitions is extended when the owner is healthy.  The [PartitionLoadBalancer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Shared/src/Processor/PartitionLoadBalancer.cs) implementation is fairly heavily commented, if you're interested in further details.

The values for the load balancing configuration can be seen by observing the defaults for the [`EventProcessorOptions`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/src/Primitives/EventProcessorOptions.cs) class, which influences the [`EventProcessor<TPartition>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.primitives.eventprocessor-1?view=azure-dotnet-preview&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet) class that serves as a base for the `EventProcessorClient`.

At present, the load balancing configuration is not exposed within the `EventProcessorClientOptions` in order to simplify the API surface, though that is a topic of discussion for some changes that are being worked on in the near future.